# My password validation doesn't execute properly

Tags: html, asp.net

So I'm trying to make a password verification with JS, it used to work (making the text box red when the passwords were not the same(OnKeyUp)) but wouldn't make the button block the actual register.
if you can have a look at my code i'd be really grateful thank you.

```js
function auth() {

  var password = document.getElementById("password");
  var password2 = document.getElementById("Repassword")
  var PassDont = document.getElementById("passDont")
  if (password.value != password2.value()) {
    PassDont.innerHTML = "<h3> Passwords Don't match </h3>";
    password2.style.backgroundColor = "#ff3232";
    return false;
  } else {
    password2.style.backgroundColor = "#8fff89";
    PassDont.innerHTML = " "
  }

}
```

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

  <div id="container">

    <h1 class="RegHead">Registeration</h1>

    <label class="input-label" for="username">username</label>
    <input class="user-input" type="text" id="username" name="user_name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+" maxlength="12" title="Username should be in English and numbers, 12 letters max" required autocomplete="off" />

    <br />

    <label class="input-label" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input class="user-input" type="password" id="password" name="password" pattern=".{6,12}" required title="Password have to contain between 6 to 12 letters" required autocomplete="off" />

    <br />

    <label class="input-label" for="Re-password">Re-enter Password:</label>
    <input class="user-input" type="password" id="Repassword" name="repassword" onkeyup="return auth();" autocomplete="off" />

    <br />

    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="OnSubmitClick" OnClientClick="return auth();" />

    <span id="passDont"></span>
  </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have a look into the browser console. `password2.value()` is not a function.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please REPLACE the ASP with relevant view-source HTML

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting_

Comment: replace this if (password.value != password2.value()) with if (password.value != password2.value)

Comment: you can F12 to see error in console log with password2.value()

Answer (score -1):

```
if (password.value != password2.value())
```

to

```
if (password != password2)
```

Comment: Or password.value != password2.value. Because value is not a function